# jquery post без переменной

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

В Chrome в разделе Network наблюдаю такого вида запрос

```
Request URL:https://randomdomain  
Request Method:POST  
Status Code:200 Ok 
//headers     
Accept:application/x-base64-frpc  
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language:en
Cache-Control:max-age=0  
Connection:keep-alive  
Content-Length:28
Content-type:application/x-base64-frpc 
...
```

и запрос запрос

```
Request Payload:  
yhECAGgKbm90aWZ5VXNlcjug8IEB
```

Нет переменных/параметров, запрос тупо строка. Как послать такой запрос? На php делается так:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "yhECAGgKbm90aWZ5VXNlcjug8IEB")
```

Answer (score 1):

Методика решения:

ищем в google, ходим по ссылкам и по ссылкам со ссылок и читаем, затем думаем.

Пишем тестовый запрос:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/x-base64-frpc', data: 'yhECAGgKbm90aWZ5VXNlcjug8IEB'})
```

Дидактический материал, на всякий случай:

[why i got request payload on ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545356/why-i-got-request-payload-on-ajax-request)

[What difference between “Request Payload” vs “Form Data”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome)

[What difference between form data and request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494574/what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-and-request-payload)

[и т.д.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281117/x-www-form-urlencoded-vs-json-http-post/13457437#13457437)